# My django app automatically add a /static/ to any url not specified with the {% url %} tag

Tags: django

As stated in the title of my question my app is going on production and i configured all the static parameters, everything works fine except one thing and i can't seem to find the problem.

When i make an <a href="#Description"> to get to an anchor for exemple, the link that is served is:
**[www.example.com/static/#Description](http://www.example.com/static/#Description)** instead of **[www.example.com/mypage/#Description](http://www.example.com/mypage/#Description)**

Thank you for your help !

This is my settings.py configuration:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

I've tried changing the configuration but i don't seem to find the problem.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that we can copy paste to recreate the problem ourselves. This should include all of the appropriate files needed to run a django app and duplicate the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.